# I'm stuck in a while loop in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops, while-loop

```
if((selected[0]=='H')&&(selected[1]=='Y')&&((selected[2]-'0')<=4))
{
    integer_v=10+(selected[1]*100)+(selected[2]-'0');
    printf("%d", integer_v);
}
else
{
    while((selected[0]!='H')||(selected[1]=='Y')||((selected[2]-'0')<=4))
    {
        printf("Wrong input!(%s) Please try again:\n", selected);
        scanf(" %s", re_selected);
        strcpy(selected,re_selected);
    }
    integer_v=10+(selected[1]*100)+(selected[2]-'0');
    printf("%d", integer_v);
}
```

In my project to create this simple board game I cannot get out of this while loop. The purpose of this piece of code is to check if the input I gave(selected), which is a char array, has 'H' in first, 'Y' in second, and a digit from 1 to 4 in third slots of this array. But when I do it wrong once I get stuck in the while loop(The first try is successful).  Even if the requirements are fullfilled the "Wrong input" message still appears.
Example:

```
Choose which pawn you want to move:
HY5
Wrong input!(HY5) Please try again:
HY3
Wrong input!(HY3) Please try again:
HY4
Wrong input!(HY4) Please try again:
```

In here, HY5 is truly not the required input because 5>4 but HY4 is okay but the code still does not accept it.

Comment: Where `selected` comes from? Show all the relevant code

Comment: Selected is the given input simply defined above. It is the input I give as such as HY4 or HY5.

Comment: The point is that you do not show how `selected` is defined. Is it long enough? Correct type, ...? Please always show all code required to compile a minimum example.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for heads up!. I'll give more attention to it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition of the `while` statement is wrong.

It is easy to simply add `!` to negate the first condition for checking.

```
while(!((selected[0]=='H')&&(selected[1]=='Y')&&((selected[2]-'0')<=4)))
```

Another way is negating the condition using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
while((selected[0]!='H')||(selected[1]!='Y')||((selected[2]-'0')>4))
```